# No implementation found for method getDatabasesPath on channel com.tekartik.sqflite

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a flutter app, works well on mobile, am trying to have the same app on web. am using moor to sync and store data locally incase there is no internet and when internet is back it syncs with the server. Now when I try to run the same app on the web, moor is complaining

```
Error: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getDatabasesPath on channel com.tekartik.sqflite)
```

the plugin says it supports web, from [here](https://pub.dev/packages/moor). Am not finding much information on how to resolve this, how can I configure moor to run on the web without that error?

Comment: Did you try to restart your app?

Comment: @Andrej yes I did nothing happened

Comment: Did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

The plugin moor you are using is built on top of sqlite, which itself is not supported on web, and at bottom of moor plugin page also it's mentioned that web support is experimental now.

[Sqlite plugin](https://pub.dev%20%E2%80%BA%20packages%20%E2%80%BA%20sqflite%20sqflite%20%7C%20Flutter%20Package%20-%20Pub.dev) doesn't has support for web yet, but it does support android, ios and Macos. I would suggest anyone facing this problem to use other databases or cloud based databases instead of sqlite if you are using flutter web. Hope the plugin gets supported on web also.

Update:
You can try this [example](https://github.com/rodydavis/moor_shared) to use sqlite on web, it might work.

Comment: From this [example](https://github.com/rodydavis/moor_shared) sqlite works fine from the web, you just have to be creative, it worked for me using that example so making your answer not that correct

Comment: Updated the answer!

Comment: A lot of code you have to use bloc for it to work

Answer (score -1):

Got the same error when first run the web app.
If you follow clean architecture you can easily provide the right "database" instance.

This is what I did:

1. Create a local data store **interface**
2. Check if web using **kIsWeb**
3. If **kIsWeb** it true I return an in memory cache otherwise I just return the mobile app database that you already implemented for you Android and iOS apps